# bazel: sema annotation and sub directory

Tags: java, build, annotations, bazel

I am trying to migrate from maven to bazel.
I have a weird behavior with java_library (and annotation processor):

I have a sub-directory where there is a BUILD file.

Something like appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/BUILD:

```
java_library(
    name = "appdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = [
        ":mysema_query",
        …
    ],
)

java_plugin(
    name = "mysema_query_plugin",
    processor_class = "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor",
    deps = [
        "@guava_jar//jar",
        "@javax_inject_jar//jar",
        "@javax_persistence_jar//jar",
        "@mysema_codegen_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_apt_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_codegen_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_core_jar//jar",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "mysema_query",
    exported_plugins = [":mysema_query_plugin"],
    exports = [
        "@guava_jar//jar",
        "@javax_inject_jar//jar",
        "@javax_persistence_jar//jar",
        "@mysema_codegen_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_apt_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_codegen_jar//jar",
        "@querydsl_core_jar//jar",
    ],
)
```

When I compile it, it works fine, i.e.

```
bazel build -s //appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl:appdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl
```

But when I use a “global” BUILD file:

/BUILD:

```
java_library(
  name = "appdirect-parent",
  srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
  deps = [
    …
    "appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl:appdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl",
  ],
)
```

It fails with:

```
$ bazel build --jobs 1 -s //:all

INFO: Analysed 238 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 238 targets...
SUBCOMMAND: # //appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl:appdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl [action 'Compiling Java headers appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/libappdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl-hjar.jar (8 files) and running 
annotation processors (AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor)']
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_nicolas.zin/a2e37cae9143f2d5cb81548a1629daf9/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 \
  external/local_jdk/bin/java -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/p:external/bazel_tools/third_party/java/jdk/langtools/javac-9+181-r4173-1.jar -jar external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/turbine_deploy.jar @bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/libappdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl-hjar.jar-2.params)
ERROR: /Users/nicolas.zin/Documents/git/AppDirect.bazel/appdirect-parent/appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/BUILD:5:1: Compiling Java headers appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/libappdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl-hjar.jar 
(8 files) and running annotation processors 
(AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor) failed (Exit 1)
appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/src/main/java/com/appdirect/backend/sms/gateway/settings/dao/SmsGatewaySettingsDAOImpl.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QSmsGatewaySettings
  location: package com.appdirect.backend.sms.gateway.settings
appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/src/main/java/com/appdirect/backend/sms/gateway/settings/dao/SmsGatewaySettingsDAOImpl.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QSmsGatewaySettings
  location: class com.appdirect.backend.sms.gateway.settings.dao.SmsGatewaySettingsDAOImpl
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.172s, Critical Path: 1.71s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

QSmsGatewaySettings is a class generated by the sema annotation plugin

It is like the bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/appdirect-sms-gateway/appdirect-sms-gateway-settings-impl/libappdirect_sms_gateway_settings_impl-gensrc.jar file is not taken into account

Does someone faced the same problem?
Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Of course I have to post the question to find the answer:

I need to introduce a

```
generates_api = True
```

i.e:

```
java_library(
    name = "mysema_query",
    generates_api = True,
    exported_plugins = [":mysema_query_plugin"],
    exports = [
        "@guava_jar//jar",
...
```